# Checking big theta, little oh and little omega with limits?

Tags: big-o, little-o

Say we have two functions f(n) and g(n). If we we wanted to check if f(n) is little oh o(g(n)) would it be valid to do the following:

```
lim n -> infinity f(n)/g(n) and the result would have to = 0 ?
```

So if the above comes out to 0, will it mean f(n) is o(g(n))? And how can we check the big theta and little omega **with limits?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes.

o(g(n)) = { f(n): for all constants c > 0, there exists a constant n0 such that 0 ≤ f(n) < cg(n) for all n ≥ n0}. 
ALSO: 0 = lim f(n)/g(n)